# How to save/export a lottie animation as a video file

Tags: android, video, lottie

I want to save a Lottie animation as video (mp4 or any other video format).

Here's a list of what I've tried:

- [How to save Lottie Animation as Video (.mp4) and GIF (.gif) in Android?](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/issues/1273)
- I tried with this [Lottie Recorder Test lib](https://github.com/rogererill/LottieRecorderTest#lottie-recorder-test). But I'm still getting [issue with this lib also](https://github.com/rogererill/LottieRecorderTest/issues/2)
- Someone told me to [record surfaceview using this lib](http://draw%20each%20frame%20of%20lottie%20onto%20the%20canvas). but [How to draw each frame of lottie onto the canvas?](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/issues/1074)

I really do know know how to draw each frame in surfaceview from Lottie

```
public class MyLottieAnimationView extends LottieAnimationView {
SurfaceHolder holder;

public void setHolder(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    this.holder = holder;
}

public MyLottieAnimationView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyLottieAnimationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyLottieAnimationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
    if (c == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot draw onto the canvas as it's null");
    } else {
        Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        canvas.setBitmap(myBitmap);

        c.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, new Paint());
//            c.
//            drawMyStuff(canvas);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

}
```

Comment: try with https://github.com/rogererill/LottieRecorderTest#lottie-recorder-test this is the best library

Answer (score 1):

```
val lottieComposition = LottieCompositionFactory.fromRawResSync(this, R.raw.android_wave) // your lottie json file 
    val lottieDrawable = LottieDrawable()
    lottieDrawable.composition = lottieComposition.value




val path = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) ?: File(cacheDir, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).apply { mkdirs() }
    val videoFile = File(path, "lottie_in_video.mp4")
    val recordingOperation = RecordingOperation(Recorder(videoOutput = videoFile), FrameCreator(lottieDrawable))
    {
      textView.text = getString(R.string.recording_finished)
      openCreatedVideo(videoFile)
    }
```

then call on save button

```
recordingOperation.start()
```

refrence : https://github.com/rogererill/LottieRecorderTest

Comment: Won't it take a lot of time to record each frame of the video?

Comment: How do I change the background? It is always black, and I already tried changing the color in `Recorder.nextFrame`  there...

Comment: Is that working if there is bitmap in json?

Comment: @BhaveshHirpara you mean base64 image in json?

Comment: @VineshChauhan Yes

Comment: @BhaveshHirpara as you can see in the ImageAssetManager.java file they are decoding base64 image to byte and then creating a bitmap so we can easily replace that base64